# ActiveX installation in Delphi 7.0

Tags: delphi, activex, installation

I am using an ActiveX component in my projects. I can add this component to Visual Studio 2010, 2008, Delphi XE2, Visual Basic 6.0, but I cannot import this into Delphi versions 5, 6 or 7.

This is the activex file in my ftp server: [Active X File](http://packia.com/er/TAK_ControlBoard.ocx)

Comment: When I choose ActiveX and Click Install Button, After Compile and install, component don't appear in pallet.
i searched in any tabs and not found.
can you download ActiveX file and test it under Delphi 7.0

Comment: Did you install it into a design time package?

Comment: Yes, i tested other ActiveX and worked. but this active x under does not add to tabs.

Comment: Yes you installed it into a design time package? Did that result in generated code with a call to `RegisterComponent`?

Comment: No, please help me to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I was brave enough to download and register this OCX and try to replicate what you did. And yes I found the same behaviour as your reported.

So, I looked at the imported type library unit in XE2. Remember that in XE2 a component appears on the palette. At the bottom of the unit is this code:

```
procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents(dtlOcxPage, [TTAK_Control]);
end;
```

This code registers the component in the palette and it is missing when the OCX is imported in Delphi 6, the only old Delphi I have to hand. Indeed the entire `TTAK_Control` component is missing from the import unit. Sometimes the import process fails.

So I simply took the imported type library file from XE2 and copied it over the top of the equivalent unit in D6. That's the unit named `TAK_ControlBoard_TLB`. When I compiled in D6 there was a compiler error because `UIntPtr` was not recognised. Replace that with `Cardinal` in D6. At that point the compilation succeeds and the component appears on the palette.

Now, when I attempt to add it to a form an OLE error is produced, but I can't really help with that since I know nothing about the component. Note that this error occurs in both XE2 and D6.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
i upload all files in the same directory of ActiveX, maybe these files can help at install time. http://packia.com/er/all.rar

Comment: In XE2, ActiveX Add and Run Successfully;

Comment: I don't understand those comments. Did you do what I said to fix the import unit in D7?

Comment: Thank you very much, i do as your note, i replace D6 Pas File With XE2 Pas File, and my problem solved.
i must check it on XP Embedded Machine tomorrow, Thank You, You are best.